# Default Reader Quota Settings

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I am currently working on a web application. Also I am using WCF web service. I had customized the reader's quota settings in web.config of my WCF like maxNameTableCharCount,maxStringContentLength according to my need.

My problem is that whenever I used to add service reference in my application It is adding the default setting of WCF.
I just want to know that how can we override these default settings. However I know that I can change these settings again in my application web.config but I want to change it automatically.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the service reference, it will create the default settings as you are aware. It is not possible to adjust these automatically.

You should only need to add the settings once and you are then free to adjust these accordingly.

If you need to update the service, just do that, rather than removing and adding again.